# My flutter builds not showing in App Store connect

Tags: xcode, flutter, app-store-connect

I archive my flutter app dozen of times but It's always like this
[image]

I tried a few solutions: Add App icon, update Xcode, enable bitcode but nothing works.
Thanks.

Comment: Please check the Apple developer email. When uploading is finished successfully or failed, you could receive an email from Apple.

Comment: Do you have any error when creating the archive ?
Does you app bundle id match in xcode and apple connect ?

Comment: check under testflight your builds should be there

Comment: @Mardel Thank you. You solved my problems. I noticed that the UI of App Store Connect changed a bit. Thank you all of you for your help

Comment: You are welcome. Upvote my comment if it is helpful. :)

Comment: @Phuc facing same problem , what did you do?

Comment: @FahmiSawalha Just check your email. It will show you what problems are.